# Outlook Html Signature: Background Images

Tags: html, outlook, background-image, signature

Is there any possible way to display background image behind text for an HTML outlook email signature. I check few resources online and some suggested using VML tags, I tried that also didn't work. Is it possible to have a patch or a work-around to use background image for the main table of the signature.

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; width: 1705px; height: 356px; background-image: url(signature.jpg); background-repeat: repeat-y;" background="signature.jpg">
<tr>
    <td valign="top">
        <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" style="padding-left:140px; padding-top:50px;">
                    <span style="color:#000000; font-size:22px; line-height: 20px; font-weight:bold; font-family:calibri"><b>Name</b></span><br>
                    <span style="color:#000000; font-size:20px; font-family:calibri">Consultant</span><br><br>
                    <span style="color:#000000; font-size:20px; font-family:calibri">P.O.Box Location</span><br>
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                        <tr>
                            <td valign=top>
                                <span style="color:#000000; font-size:20px; font-family:calibri"><strong>T:</strong></span>
                                <span style="color:#000000; font-size:20px; font-family:calibri">+001-123-456</span>
                                <br>
                                <span style="color:#000000; font-size:20px; font-family:calibri"><strong>D:</strong></span>
                                <span style="color:#000000; font-size:20px; font-family:calibri">+001-123-456&nbsp;</span>
                                <br>
                                <span style="color:#000000; font-size:20px; font-family:calibri"><strong>E:</strong></span>
                                <a href="mailto:hello@gmail.com" target="_blank" style="color:#000000; text-decoration:none;">
                                    <span style="color:#000000; font-size:20px; font-family:calibri">hello@gmail.com</span>
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td valign=top style='padding-left:20px'>
                                <span style="color:#000000; font-size:20px; font-family:calibri"><strong>M:</strong></span>
                                <span style="color:#000000; font-size:20px; font-family:calibri"></span>
                                <br>
                                <span style="color:#000000; font-size:20px; font-family:calibri"><strong>F:</strong></span>
                                <span style="color:#000000; font-size:20px; font-family:calibri;">+971 4 367 2892</span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

Email development is not front-end development.

The only way to get background images to work in Outlook is to use vml code. The rest of us are not thrilled using it either, but it's the only way to get a background image to work in most versions of Outlook.

I tested this code in Litmus using every version of Outlook:

```html
<div style="background-color:#ff0000; width:600px;">
  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
  <v:background xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="t">
    <v:fill type="tile" src="http://www.gwally.com/news/photos/catintinfoilhat.jpg" color="#ff0000"/>
  </v:background>
  <![endif]-->
  <table height="450" width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" align="left" background="http://www.gwally.com/news/photos/catintinfoilhat.jpg">
      <h1 style="text-align: center; color: #ffffff;-webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
   -webkit-text-stroke-color: black; font-family: Arial, san-serif;">
      Background Image with text on top
      </h1>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<p>
You can find most of this code at https://backgrounds.cm.</p>

<p>That picture really is me and Canaille the cat.</p>
```

It doesn't work in Outlook 10 mail, it repeats in 2013 and 2016, it will work partially in Gmail, AOL, Yahoo because they do not fully support background images.

- https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/color-background/background/
- https://jsfiddle.net/wallyglenn/7zLaLrfx/

If you can figure out a way to make it work in Outlook without vml, you'd be a hero in the email world.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried your solution but my issue is that I have a PHP code that generates the signature in browser for the user to copy paste it directly from the browser to their Outlook Signature setup, when that is done, it is still not copying (displaying) the background image even with VML code. any suggestions?